# Python / cx_Freeze: askopenfile / askdirectory /// filedialog

Tags: python, cx-freeze, filedialog

I've got a problem.
I've got a program // script, which works perfectly, but when I compile it using cx_Freeze, it doesn't work: Name "filedialog" is not defined.
Do I have to import it on another way??
My Script part:

```
from tkinter import *
from shutil import *
import sys
import os
#Vars:
location = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])+"/"
if os.path.isfile(location+"filedic.txt"):
    file = open(location+"filedic.txt","r").read()
else:
    fiRoot = Tk()
    fiRoot.withdraw()
    file = str(filedialog.askdirectory())
```

And my setup script:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(
    name = "BlackChat",
    version = "1.3",
    description = "BlackChat was programmed by David Jandrey",
    executables = [Executable("BlackChat.py", base = base,icon = "BlackChat.ico")])
```

Thanks for coming answers.

Comment: Try doing `from tkinter import filedialog` specifically. It looks like cx_Freeze is failing to copy it for some reason.

Comment: Thank you, but I've tried that.. Well, let's try it again..

Answer (score 0):

Reposting as an answer:

Doing `from tkinter import filedialog` explicitly might make it work - it looks like cx_Freeze isn't copying the filedialog module.